# Accessing data from an API response is iOS app

Tags: ios, api, nsarray, nsobject

I have this iOS app I am working on and when I make a call to the API, I get this kind of data set back:

```
{
    "finished_on" = 1414499584;
    id = 4370760;
    ip = "1.1.1.1";
    mode = 1;
    name = asdasdasdasd1;
    remaining = 420;
    score = 0;
    "simulation_block" = 0;
    "simulation_id" = 0;
    "simulation_type" = 0;
    "started_on" = 1414499583;
    status = "-1";
    step = 1;
    total = 5;
}
```

The API call uses this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

And the response is coming from [responseObject description].

This all works and works everywhere else in my app. No problem there. Just confused on how I can work with this data for some reason.

Can anyone tell me how I can access parts of this data? For example, I'm wanting to pull out the "name". When I inspect the data in XCode, it's telling me it is a NSObject. And I've tried converting that down to a JSON string and other ways, but I'm having no luck.

Comment: Show your relevant code that gets this result from the API.

Comment: You say you don't know why posting the code would help. Thanks to the code, people now know what you are doing and it is now possible to offer an answer to your question. People now know that you are getting back an `NSDictionary` response and the output is simply a log of the dictionary.

Comment: It would now help to show how you get and try to use the "name" value and you should explain what issue you have doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `description` directive, which outputs an NSString representation of the data contained by that object. You need to access the actual contents of the object returned into `responseObject` with something akin to:

```
responseObject[@"name"];
```

... but the implementation depends on exactly how AFNetworking is returning your `responseObject`.